# Problems with encoding when inputting a TiKz picture

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings

I'm having problems inputting a Ti*k*Z picture in a document that is encoded with UTF-8. The Ti*k*Z picture was generated with `matlab2tikz`.

When I try to open the `foo.tikz` file with my editor (Texmaker), it says:

```
The file cannot be read correctly with the default enconding (UTF-8).
Use the following codification: ISO-8859-1
```

My preamble is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
blà blà blà
blà blà blà
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \newlength\figureheight
  \newlength\figurewidth
  \setlength\figureheight{6cm}
  \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
  \input{foo.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I input the `foo.tikz` file in my document, an error happens because some of the characters included are undefined in input-encoding 'utf8'.

The problem is that I have to use UTF-8 encoding because I'm not writing in English and I have to use a lot of accents and other characters.

What can I do in order to input this picture in my document? I thought about using multiple encodings in the document, but I don't know if this can be done. Or converting the Ti*k*Z file to utf8 encoding, but I don't know how I could do this, if possible.

Comment: Is your Ti*k*Z file saved as UTF8? Check with some editor. We cant help here, as we do not see the problematic Ti*k*Z code. Please add it to your OP. If you have really fancy stuff in you image, you could compile it separately and insert the resulting PDF to your document.

Comment: I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks! And that is a good idea since the plot is too dense. I will try to compile it separately and inserting the PDF to my document. So that, I don't have to deal with encoding problems.

Comment: From your description seems like `matlab2tikz` file is encoded in `ISO-8859-1` while TeXMaker tries to read it with `utf8` encoding. You can change TeXmaker encoding under `Options`+`Editor`. Although it's better to use it, you don't need to use `utf8` for accents, `latin1` is enough.

Comment: Ah! i benvingut! Ja som més.

Comment: @Ignasi Gràcies! I could do it finally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell LaTeX to use another input encoding locally:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
blà blà blà
blà blà blà
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \newlength\figureheight
  \newlength\figurewidth
  \setlength\figureheight{6cm}
  \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
  \begingroup
  \inputencoding{latin1} % or whatever
  \input{foo.tikz}
  \endgroup
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In this case it should work without problem, but I wouldn't recommend it in all cases: If auxiliary files are involved (glossaries, index, etc) mixing encodings can get confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked fine without having to compile the picture separately.